# Error on PlugUpdate

Tags: macos, neovim

I'm currently running on Mac with Neovim and [Vim Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).
Whenever I run the commend `:PlugUpdate`, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>2_job_handler:
line   19:
E121: Undefined variable: self
```

I've also tried to update the plugins one by one, and the error still comes up.

And no plugins are updated.
I've tried to update neovim to the latest version as well, yet the error still occur.

Does anyone know where the error comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was Vim Plug itself.

I had to run `:PlugUpgrade` to update Vim Plug, then run `:PlugInstall` to fix the errors.

Leaving this here for people who will have the same issue. :)